# guava synchronizedSortedSetMultimap compareto nullpointerexception

Tags: nullpointerexception, guava, multimap, compareto

I use guava synchronizedSortedSetMultimap to save data:

```
 public static final Multimap<TimestampedDeviceId, ParsedPayload> multimap = Multimaps.synchronizedSortedSetMultimap(
            TreeMultimap.create(new Comparator<TimestampedDeviceId>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(TimestampedDeviceId o1, TimestampedDeviceId o2) {
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
                }
            }, new Comparator<ParsedPayload>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(ParsedPayload o1, ParsedPayload o2) {
                    return o1.getCurrentPkgNum()-o2.getCurrentPkgNum();
                }
            }));
```

The key of the map is the combination of timestamp and devID:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TimestampedDeviceId implements Comparable<TimestampedDeviceId> {
    String deviceId;
    TimeStamp timeStamp;


    @Override
    public int compareTo(TimestampedDeviceId o) {
//        log.info("o:{},{}",o,timeStamp);
        if(!deviceId.equals(o.deviceId)){
            return deviceId.compareTo(o.deviceId);
        }
        else {
            return timeStamp.compareTo(o.getTimeStamp());
        }    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TimestampedDeviceId that = (TimestampedDeviceId) o;
        return Objects.equals(deviceId, that.deviceId) &&
                Objects.equals(timeStamp, that.timeStamp);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(deviceId, timeStamp);
    }
    
}
```

And the data comes in order, when first data coming, I got the exception:

```
2021-03-18 10:03:06.284 INFO  com.aier.camerawater.service.OnenetService - id:"668609823",total:28,current:1,time:{"day":18,"hour":10,"minute":3,"month":3,"second":4,"year":2021},exception:{}
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.aier.camerawater.model.TimeStamp.compareTo(TimeStamp.java:39)
        at com.aier.camerawater.model.TimestampedDeviceId.compareTo(TimestampedDeviceId.java:24)
        at com.aier.camerawater.util.Common$1.compare(Common.java:32)
        at com.aier.camerawater.util.Common$1.compare(Common.java:28)
        at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:376)
        at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:345)
        at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:278)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap.put(AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java:184)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractSetMultimap.put(AbstractSetMultimap.java:137)
        at com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap.put(TreeMultimap.java:74)
        at com.google.common.collect.Synchronized$SynchronizedMultimap.put(Synchronized.java:636)
        at com.aier.camerawater.service.OnenetService.parse(OnenetService.java:92)
        at com.aier.camerawater.controller.OnenetController.receive(OnenetController.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

It dosen't make sense why the first data cause the comoareTo method NPE.
Any help will be grateful

Comment: Are you sure`deviceIid` field isn't null?

Comment: no it's not, as you can see above the exception，I print the id

Comment: `log.info("o:{},{}",o,timeStamp);` prints argument to `compareTo`, I'm asking about whether `this.deviceId` is null or not, same applies for `this.timeStamp`.